# Proving a function from a cartesian set to a set is onto

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

CONTEXT: Question made up by uni lecturer.

How do you prove that a function mapping from a Cartesian product of the integers to the integers is onto?

The function is $f:Z$x$Z$ to $Z$ where $f((m,n))=2m-n$.

I'm pretty sure the function is onto, since I can't think of an integer that can't be written in terms of $2m-n$ where $m$ and $n$ are integers, but am unsure of how to show this.

Comment: You can take $m=0$, so this is really fairly straightforward.

Slightly more challenging: is $f((m,n)) = 2m-3n$ surjective?

Comment: @JaneDoé doesn't surjective and onto mean the same thing?

Comment: @RubyPa yes it is.

Comment: Sorry, yes, "surjective" and "onto" mean the same thing, so much so that I switch to saying "surjective" without thinking! The point is that it is slightly harder to see that $f((m,n)) = 2m-3n$ is onto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Set $m=0$. $~~~~~~~~~~~~$

Answer (score 1):

$f((n,n))=2n-n=n,$ so any $n\in\mathbb Z$ has $(n,n) \in \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ in its pre-image.

Comment: This is an alternative to [Jane Doé](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/670243/jane-do%c3%a9's)'s suggestion and could be adapted to solve the slightly more challenging question.